# Transmission repair or replacement

Tags: transmission, dodge, durango

What type of automatic transmission’s can I put on my 1999 dodge Durango 5.9L v8 magnum 4 wheel drive??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.